# GPIO Power off on shutdown with retropie

Tags: gpio, power, retropie, relay, shutdown

i asked this question before but i have added a diagram to explain it more clearly.
I am building a retropie arcade machine with a raspberry pi. I have added a shutdown / startup button to shutdown and boot up the pi without just cutting the power and therefore corrupting the SD Image.
But there is a problem. Everything else, the fans, CRT monitor, Marquee light, amplifier and more are running on AC power, and these have to be turned off manually with a seperate AC Switch. So to turn off the cabinet, i first need to press the button to shut down the pi, and when it finishes, flip the AC Switch. I would prefer it all to go off in one go.
So my plan, as shown in the diagram, is to have the pi constantly powered, but when it shuts down, a relay being powered by the GPIO shuts off, therefore shutting off the rest of the machine. and to start it up again, i press the button to start the Pi, powering the Relay, starting everything else.
However, even in shutdown state, the powered GPIO pins continue to supply power. While the USB power does shut off in shutdown state, i don't really want my relay powered off the USB ports, as they will all be occupied by the end of the project. I also dont want to solder onto the board itself.
So, In Simple terms, is it possible to code the GPIO pins in Retropie to give out a 3.3v or 5v signal when powered on, and no power when the pi is in shutdown state? if so, how would i do this?
Thanks in advance. Check the diagram in the link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1BME.jpg

Comment: Just didnt make myself very clear so redid it.

Comment: well can you help me